# Using Flexbuilder to create an AIR app connected to Saleforce.com, how can I encrypt the local datastore?

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite, encryption, air, salesforce

I have created an Adobe AIR application that interfaces with Salesforce.com.  The only drawback I have is that the data that is synced to the desktop is not encrypted.  I can encrypt a database that I create locally, however, I am trying to encrypt the database that is created and maintained by the flexforforce toolkit.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: So, you want to encrypt a database that is create and managed by classes that you have no control over? Why is this needed?

Comment: Yes the toolkit manages the connection and syncing, however the .db is plain(ish) text and can be opened and read by a sqlite admin tool.  I would like to encrypt to obfuscate sensitive data on the desktop.

Comment: erm, why?  people that have access to the computer will have access to the application and the data or can go directly to the data so your security 'measure' is illogical.  Furthermore, by 'encrypting' a database without changing how the db is read/managed means you're effectively making your data useless.  If anything, you'd want to encrypt your hard drive and employ good security practices on the OS level.

Comment: The application is password protected, same credentials as their Salesforce.com account.  Yes, the best security is an encrypted HD, however the company I am developing for is not "there" yet.  I am trying to do my part to make sure the application is protected.

Comment: Tell salesforce to get off their ass and do something about the security?  There's no other real solution without having a massive hack.

Comment: @J_A_X, You can try, but salesforce reps will direct you to post this to IdeaExchange where it would need to be massively upvoted to get through. The advanced ideas never really get the juice because the masses don't need or understand them. Maybe better option is to involve legal and let them tell salesforce they are exposing sensitive data. Might get them in gear.

Answer (score 0):

J_A_X is correct, without access to the underlying code communicating to the database, it would be damn near impossible, however it appears the situation has changed.

AFAICT SalesBuilder is using a locally encrypted air database: http://coenraets.org/blog/2008/11/salesbuilder-15-with-new-air-15-database-encryption/.  It appears the source code is available for this application, and thus a possibily that you might be able to pull the libraries this is using?  Or perhaps the libraries you are using are in fact already encrypting the database?

Comment: AIR has the capabilities, as a matter of fact I also have a local database for non-Salesforce information.  I have verified the database is NOT encrypted.  I am thinking I might be able to extend one of the Salesforce packages, but not sure where to start.

Comment: I would download their source for those sample application that are already using an encrypted salesforce database and see how they are interacting with the Data Access Layer, should be a start in the right direction hopefully.